# Differences of "no" "there is no" and "there is not"

Tags: difference

When to use them? What is the difference? For example:

> No problem.
> There is no problem.
> There is not problem.

Answer (score 1):

> No problem.

This is slang but it is often heard in casual conversation.

> There is not problem.

This is incorrect as it's missing an article.  You might say: "There is not a problem." or "There are not any problems."

> There is no problem.

This is correct.